# Ping works, other commands fail

Tags: proxy, ping, wget

I'm behind a proxy at work.
When I try to ping google, it works.

When I try to wget, I got stuck on the "Connecting to [proxy name]". I tried both via the "google.com" adress and via the IP adress I got with the ping.

Every other command fails while trying to connect to the proxy. Other people around me don't have this issue. I triple checked the proxy adress/port.

I saw that this could be due to ipv6 use. I disabled it without success.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1
```

My browser works well so I can surf, and I use another proxy at home, without issue this time.

I'm under Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Can you give us the output of `nmap` and `service iptables status`? Are your ports open? did you `traceroute` to see where the problem is?

Comment: Could you please give me the full commands ? I'm not familiar with those. Also, I should add that I'm not trying to configure a server. I'm just behind a proxy at my university, that strangely timeout/doesn't connect when I apt-get/wget while other people can.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I really want to help but I don't think I should google it for you. If you really want to learn you can do that yourself, then I can help you answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

`wget` typically uses whatever proxy is set in `http_proxy` environment variable.

You can check the settings with

```
echo $http_proxy
```

and set a new one with

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy:port/
```

Make sure that this configuration matches the one in your browser.

Comment: This is the correct answer.   I ran into the same issue a year or so ago and adding the proxy allows you to wget sites on the internet.

Comment: Nope, I checked, double checked and triple checked :/
http_proxy and https_proxy are set correctly.

Comment: Can you put the output of your `echo $http_proxy` and `echo $HTTP_PROXY`. Same with https. Sometimes lowercase isn't enough.